# Understanding what diverge means for a scalar potential.

Tags: calculus

I have a scalar potential given by:

$$
\phi=-\frac{1}{2(n+1)}\left[{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{n+1}}\right]
$$

I am then asked for what value of the exponent $n$ does the scalar potential ($\phi$, above) diverge at both the origin and infinity.

N.B. I am not asking for someone to give me the answer to that, but instead rather explain what is meant by diverge and then how to figure out the value $n$ which diverges at the origin and infinity.

Comment: I suppose for $n=-1$ the scalar potential is undefined everywhere.

Comment: Usually it just means: is the limit at whatever point existing and finite?

Comment: Ok, so how would I go about figuring this out...

Comment: It diverges at the origin for $n<-1$ and diverges as $\vec r\to \infty$ for $n>-1$.  It is undefined for $n=-1$.  And that is that.

Comment: Not that I disagree with you, but say it was $2(n+3)$ as the denominator would it diverge at the origin for $n=-3$ etc etc?